# Using Google Script w/ built-in Geocoder class for addr to (lat, lon) conversion; error daily limit. Got Geocoding API key, no mention in Geocoder dox

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

Google has pages about [javascript requests through Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), and it has [pages about the Geocoder Class in Scripts](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

Both services take street addresses and turn them into latitude and longitude and are from Google. There is no documentation on it but **I feel like there must be some way to include the API key in the body of the request**, I've come away empty handed and wall 1 of google support was not helpful.

Here is the error I receive after a thousand or so queries in a day:

[WOMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80QN4.png)

Can anyone shed any light on this? I am newer at coding but I am successfully using POST and GET commands out of Google Scripts with multiple other API's and I just can't believe Google would cut you off for Geocoder class requests and not give you the option to pay for the privilege.

It would be so unlike them.

Comment: here you see the detailed products and their limitation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#:~:text=While%20you%20are%20no%20longer,side%20and%20server%2Dside%20queries.

Answer (score 0):

Further elaborating the limits in that documentation mentioned by @john, Geocoding API `Web service` and Geocoding with `JavaScript service` have different use cases.

With the Web Service APIs you make explicit server side HTTP requests to Google's servers. Global rate limit of 50 queries per second, geared towards `"batch processing"`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits

With the JavaScript services, the service is automatically loaded in the browser when you request the JavaScript API. Per user-session rate limit, geared towards "normal expected" `user-interaction`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#rate-limits

Specific numbers/details are not shared publicly. (but you can actually test this and see for yourself
https://jsbin.com/tidapetose/1/edit?html,output. This is an example for the Geocoding Service, but the similar rate limiting applies for other services.
If you want to send more than 10 requests at once, you shouldn't use the Maps JavaScript API services but the Web Service APIs (i.e. make server side requests instead.)